# How to put checkbox in each CMFCTabCtrl's tab header

Tags: mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I have a MFC application. I am using CMFCTabCtrl in a dialog.

My requirement is I have to add a checkbox in each tab page of CMFCTabCtrl as below.

[image]

Is it possible to add checkbox in each tab page of CMFCTabCtrl ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was answered in the below link.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2b86a6df-12bb-4fe2-9f23-d9848de49f84/adding-checkbox-in-cmfctabctrls-tab-header?forum=vcgeneral#000673ca-c995-42d8-85c2-cb4781090653

**The code is**

```
BOOL CMyDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // TODO:  Add extra initialization here
    CRect rectDummy;
    rectDummy.SetRectEmpty();
    if(!m_tab.Create(CMFCTabCtrl::STYLE_3D_VS2005, rectDummy, this, 1))
    {
    TRACE0("Failed to create output tab window\n");
    return -1;      // fail to create
    }

    m_tab.SetResizeMode(CMFCTabCtrl::RESIZE_NO);
    m_tab.SetLocation(CMFCTabCtrl::LOCATION_TOP);

    CRect rc;
    GetClientRect(rc);
    m_tab.MoveWindow(0, 200, rc.right, 200);

    const DWORD dwStyle = LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL;
    if (!m_wndOutputBuild.Create(dwStyle, rectDummy, &m_tab, 2) ||
        !m_wndOutputDebug.Create(dwStyle, rectDummy, &m_tab, 3) ||
        !m_wndOutputFind.Create(dwStyle, rectDummy, &m_tab, 4))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create output windows\n");
        return -1;      // fail to create
    }

    CString strTabName;
    BOOL bNameValid;

    // Attach list windows to tab:
    m_tab.AddTab(&m_wndOutputBuild, L"     First", (UINT)0);
    m_tab.AddTab(&m_wndOutputDebug, L"     Second", (UINT)1);
    m_tab.AddTab(&m_wndOutputFind,  L"     Third", (UINT)2);

    m_tab.init();

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
                  // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
} myTabCtrl.h
#pragma once
#include "afxtabctrl.h"
class myTabCtrl : public CMFCTabCtrl
{
public:
    myTabCtrl();
    ~myTabCtrl();
    void init();

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

    CButton m_Check1;
    CButton m_Check2;
    CButton m_Check3;
    virtual LRESULT WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
}; myTabCtrl.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "myTabCtrl.h"


myTabCtrl::myTabCtrl()
{
}


myTabCtrl::~myTabCtrl()
{
}

void myTabCtrl::init()
{
    CRect rc1, rc2, rc3;
    GetTabRect(0, rc1);
    GetTabRect(1, rc2);
    GetTabRect(2, rc3);

    m_Check1.Create(_T("Chkbox1"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_CHECKBOX, CRect(0, 0, 13, 13), this, 1234);
    m_Check2.Create(_T("Chkbox2"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_CHECKBOX, CRect(0, 0, 13, 13), this, 1235);
    m_Check3.Create(_T("Chkbox3"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_CHECKBOX, CRect(0, 0, 13, 13), this, 1236);


    m_Check1.MoveWindow(rc1.left + 20, rc1.top + 3, 13, 13);
    m_Check2.MoveWindow(rc2.left + 20, rc2.top + 3, 13, 13);
    m_Check3.MoveWindow(rc3.left + 20, rc3.top + 3, 13, 13);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(myTabCtrl, CMFCTabCtrl)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

LRESULT myTabCtrl::WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (wParam == 1234)
        {
            BOOL checked = m_Check1.GetCheck();
            m_Check1.SetCheck(!checked);
        }
        else if (wParam == 1235)
        {
            BOOL checked = m_Check2.GetCheck();
            m_Check2.SetCheck(!checked);
        }
        else if (wParam == 1236)
        {
            BOOL checked = m_Check3.GetCheck();
            m_Check3.SetCheck(!checked);
        }
        break;
    }

    return CMFCTabCtrl::WindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with creating a check box window over the current `CMFCTabCtrl`.

My advice would be:

1. Implement your own `Draw3dFlat` or `Draw3dTab` functions. This function should draw the checkbox into the tab surface.
2. You may overwrite `AdjustTabs` to resize them to the size you want.
3. Implement your own `OnLButtonDown` handler that tracks if the user clicks into your checkbox...

You have all the original source code, it should be possible to implement this in using existing code.